# Scrapy only crawling 1 page

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my Scrapy code ...

```
import scrapy

class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "news"
start_urls = ['http://www.StartURL.com/scrapy/all-news-listing']
allowed_domains = ["www.xxxxx.com"]

def parse(self, response):
    for news in response.xpath('head'):
        yield {
    'pagetype': news.xpath('//meta[@name="pdknpagetype"]/@content').extract(),
    'pagetitle': news.xpath('//meta[@name="pdknpagetitle"]/@content').extract(),
    'pageurl': news.xpath('//meta[@name="pdknpageurl"]/@content').extract(),
    'pagedate': news.xpath('//meta[@name="pdknpagedate"]/@content').extract(),
    'pagedescription': news.xpath('//meta[@name="pdknpagedescription"]/@content').extract(),
    'bodytext': [' '.join(item.split()) for item in (response.xpath('//div[@class="module__contentp"]/*/node()/text()').extract())],
        }

    next_page = response.css('p a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

My ***start_urls*** page looks like the following. It a very simple page and list all the 3000 links/URLs I want to crawl ...

```
<html>
<head>
<div>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/asdas-sdf/kkm">Page 1</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/vdfvd-asda/vdfvf/dfvd">Page 2</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/oiijo/uoiu/xwswd">Page 3</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/jnkjn-yutyy/hjj-sdf/plm">Page 4</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/unhb-oiiuio/hbhb/jhjh/qwer">Page 5</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/eres/popo-hbhh/oko-sdf/ynyt">Page 6</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/yhbb-ytyu/oioi/rtgb/ttyht">Page 7</a></p>
..........
<p><a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/iojoij/uhuh/page3000">Page 3000</a></p>
</div>
</head>
</html>
```

When I send Scrapy to this page, it just crawl the first link i.e. *http://www.xxxxx.com/page1* and stops. **No errors reported. Seems like this recursion part is not quite working...**! So how do I modify this code to go to each of these 3000 urls and then fetch some specific fields.

I saw in some other similar problems, people have used "Rules" and Scrapy's "LinkExtractor" object? I am not sure if I need either of these as my requirements are very simple.

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example url? The next_page url is probably getting filtered by dupe filter, so your next_page url discovery is probably flawed here. Usually you're looking for url that says next_page or follows the div of a page that is not hyperlinked. If you could provice an example it would be easier to explain.

Comment: I have found a solution.....  Please see my updated code below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I doubted, it was indeed a flaw in the recursion logic.

The following code solved my problem....

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "pdknnews"
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/scrapy/all-news-listing/']
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        for news in response.xpath('head'):
     yield {
        'pagetype': news.xpath('.//meta[@name="pdknpagetype"]/@content').extract(),
        'pagetitle': news.xpath('.//meta[@name="pdknpagetitle"]/@content').extract(),
        'pageurl': news.xpath('.//meta[@name="pdknpageurl"]/@content').extract(),
        'pagedate': news.xpath('.//meta[@name="pdknpagedate"]/@content').extract(),
        'pagedescription': news.xpath('.//meta[@name="pdknpagedescription"]/@content').extract(),
        'bodytext': [' '.join(item.split()) for item in (response.xpath('.//div[@class="module__content"]/*/node()/text()').extract())],
            }
    for url in hxs.xpath('//ul[@class="scrapy"]/li/a/@href').extract():
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

The last 2 lines did the recursion magic ...

Answer (score 0):

Each time you request a page like `http://www.xxxxx.com/page1`, you may get same result on `next_page = response.css('p a::attr(href)').extract_first()` if the page's page bar dose not change.
There is better way to do it :

```
start_urls = ['http://www.xxxxx.com/page{}'.format(i) for i in range(the last page number)]
```

In this way, you do not need to use callback.

And `allowed_domains = ["www.xxxxx.com"]` is not required in this code, this maybe another reason.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The page base URL does change/vary.